# Function works in console but doesn't display in page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add new title and url. I created a new function ( createBookmark ). It works fine and it shows the date in console.log within a page but it's not adding the new property and url. It's blank.

- first click left side name list
- than click Create Bookmark
- fill the form detail
- than click Create data not add in the list

```js
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);
myapp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){

$scope.lists = [

{'id' : 0, 'name' : 'Manu'},
{'id' : 1, 'name' : 'Rajveer'},
{'id' : 2, 'name' : 'Heament'},
{'id' : 3, 'name' : 'Yogesh'},
{'id' : 5, 'name' : 'Sajid'},


];

$scope.languages = [
{'id' : 0, 'title' : 'Angular', 'url' : 'http://angularjs.org', "category": "Manu"},
{'id' : 1, 'title' : 'Html5', 'url' : 'http://www.html5rocks.com/en/', "category": "Manu"},
{'id' : 2, 'title' : 'BootStrap', 'url' : 'http://getbootstrap.com/', "category": "Rajveer"},
{'id' : 3, 'title' : 'Css', 'url' : 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/', "category": "Yogesh"},
{'id' : 4, 'title' : 'emberjs', 'url' : 'http://emberjs.com/', "category": "Heament"},
{'id' : 5, 'title' : 'Javascript', 'url' : 'https://www.javascript.com/', "category": "Rajveer"},
{'id' : 6, 'title' : 'jQuery', 'url' : 'https://jquery.com/', "category": "Yogesh"},
{'id' : 7, 'title' : 'Photoshop', 'url' : 'http://www.photoshop.com/', "category": "Sajid"},
{'id' : 8, 'title' : 'Coral Draw', 'url' : 'http://www.coreldraw.com/in/', "category": "Heament"},
{'id' : 9, 'title' : 'Flash', 'url' : 'https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/', "category": "Sajid"},

];

$scope.currentCategory = null;

function setCurrentCategory(category){

 $scope.currentCategory = category;
 cancelCreating();
 cancelediting();

}

function isCurrentCategory(category){

 return $scope.currentCategory !== null && category.name === $scope.currentCategory.name;
 
}

$scope.isCurrentCategory = isCurrentCategory
$scope.setCurrentCategory = setCurrentCategory;

// -------------- Add new bookmark--------------

function resetCreateForm(){
 $scope.newBookmark = {

  title : '',
  url :'',
  category : $scope.currentCategory,

 }

}

function createBookmark(language){

 language.id = $scope.languages.length;
 $scope.languages.push(language);
 //console.log(language);

 resetCreateForm();

 //console.log(resetCreateForm());
}

$scope.createBookmark = createBookmark;
// -------------- Add new bookmark--------------
// Edit bookmar create a toggle start


$scope.isCreating = false;
$scope.isEditing = false;

function startCreating(){
$scope.isCreating = true;
$scope.isEditing = false;

resetCreateForm();
}

function cancelCreating(){
$scope.isCreating = false;

}

function startEditing(){
$scope.isCreating = false;
$scope.isEditing = true;

}

function cancelediting(){
$scope.isEditing = false;

}

function shouldShowCreating(){

 return $scope.currentCategory && !$scope.isEditing;
}

function shouldShowEditing(){

 return $scope.isEditing && !$scope.isCreating;
}

$scope.startCreating = startCreating;
$scope.cancelCreating = cancelCreating;
$scope.startEditing = startEditing;
$scope.cancelediting = cancelediting;
$scope.shouldShowCreating = shouldShowCreating;
$scope.shouldShowEditing = shouldShowEditing;

// toggle start

});
```

```css
.left_box{background-color: #909090; padding: 0px;}
.right_box{padding-top: 25px;}
.nav__box{

  padding-top: 25px;
}
.nav__box ul{ padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
.nav__box ul li {list-style: none; padding: 10px; text-align: center;}
.nav__box ul li a{
font-size: 16px;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;


}
.nav__box ul li a:hover{background: }
.language_list { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }

.language_list li{list-style: none; padding: 5px 10px; margin-bottom: 2px; border: solid 1px #ededed} 
.language_list li a {text-decoration: none; padding-left: 15px}
.remove{float: right; font-size: 12px; color: red; line-height: 16px;}
.edit{font-size: 12px; color: red; line-height: 16px; }
.active{background-color: #ffffff}
.create_bookmark{padding-top: 25px}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" class="container-fluid" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div class="row">
  <article class="col-md-1 left_box">
  <a href="" ng-click="setCurrentCategory(null)"><img  src="images/logo.png" alt="AngularJs"/></a>

  <nav class="nav__box">
   <ul>
   <li ng-repeat='list in lists' ng-class="{'active':isCurrentCategory(list)}"> 
        <a href="#" ng-click="setCurrentCategory(list)">{{list.name}}</a>
        </li>
    
   </ul>

  </nav>

  </article>
  <article class="col-md-11 right_box">
   
  <ul class="language_list">
   <li ng-repeat= "language in languages | filter:{category:currentCategory.name}">
   <span ng-click="startEditing()">Edit</span>
   <a href='{{language.url}}' target="_blank">{{language.title}}</a>
   <span class="remove">Close</span>
   </li>

  </ul>

  <div class="create_bookmark" ng-if="shouldShowCreating()">
   <button type="button" ng-click="startCreating()"> Create Bookmark</button>


<form role="form"  ng-show="isCreating" ng-submit="createBookmark(newBookmark)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="newBookmarkTitle">Bookmark Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newBookmarkTitle" ng-model="newBookmark.title">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="newBookmarkURL">Bookmark URl</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newBookmarkURL" ng-model="newBookmark.url">
  </div>
 
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancelCreating()">cancel</button>
</form>







   

  </div>
  
  <div ng-if="shouldShowEditing()">create a bookmark

 <button type="button" ng-click="cancelediting()">cancel</button>
  </div>
 
  </article>

 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I created 2 bookmarks from your code snippet. What does not work?

Comment: where i use ng-href ???

Comment: try this `<a href='' ng-href='{{language.url}}' >{{language.title}}</a>`

Comment: guys when i check my code in snippet is working fine. but its not working in my local server...